# Graph theory references for self study.

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I am trying to do some research in graph theory. I will be extremely grateful if someone helps me by suggesting some books/other sources on graph theory which explains in detail different classes of graphs with special names like circulant graphs, grey graph, Hanoi graphs etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of research do you want to do?

Comment: References for [Circulant graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_graph).

Answer (score 3):

It depends a bit on your prior knowledge. The book that helped me most in getting started was Reinhard Diestel: Graph Theory. The lastest edition (5th edition) is from 2017.

The character of this book is graduate-level with a focus on concepts, i.e. no focus on applications or algorithms.